# RadioGroupButton deselect value when button is clicked in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin

I've been working on an online exam project and currently adding some multiple choice feature. My problem is, each time I moved to the next question the value from the previous radiogroupbutton is removed/deselect. But still the assigned value of the object is present.

I tried removing/adding the component as well, still the selected value for the RadioGroupButton is missing.

```
public class TestQuestionaire extends Dialog {

TQCoverageService tqcs = new TQCoverageServiceImpl();
CellItemService cis = new CellItemServiceImpl();
ItemKeyService iks = new ItemKeyServiceImpl();

VerticalLayout mainLayout;
TQCoverage tqCoverage;
List<CellItem> ciList = new ArrayList();
Map<CellItem, CellItemOption> cellItemAnswerMap = new HashMap();
CellItem cellItem;
Binder<CellItem> binder;

private int tqCoverageId;
private int cellItemIndex = 0;
private int cellItemIndexSize = 0;
private int score = 0;

Button next;
Button prev;
String stem;
Paragraph stemHolder;
RadioButtonGroup<CellItemOption> cioGroup;

public TestQuestionaire(int tqCoverageId) {
    this.tqCoverageId = tqCoverageId;

    tqCoverage = tqcs.findTQCoverage(tqCoverageId);
    cellItemIndexSize = tqCoverage.getTotalItems();

    for(TQItems tqi : tqcs.findAllTQItems(tqCoverageId)){
        cellItem = cis.findCellItem(tqi.getCellItemId());

        List<CellItemOption> cioList = cis.findAllItemOptions(tqi.getCellItemId());
        cellItem.setCellItemOptionList(cioList);

        ItemKey ik = iks.findItemKey(tqi.getItemKeyId());
        cellItem.setItemKey(ik);

        TQAnswerKey tqak = tqcs.findTQAnswerKeyByTQItem(tqi.getTqItemId());
        cellItem.setTQAnswerKey(tqak);

        cellItemAnswerMap.put(cellItem, new CellItemOption());

        ciList.add(cellItem);
    }

    stemHolder = new Paragraph();
    stemHolder.setWidthFull();
    stemHolder.getStyle().set("font-weight", "500");

    Hr hr = new Hr();
    hr.setWidthFull();

    cioGroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
    cioGroup.setRenderer(new TextRenderer<>(CellItemOption::getCellItemOption));
    cioGroup.addThemeVariants(RadioGroupVariant.LUMO_VERTICAL);
    cioGroup.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        if(event.getValue() == null){
            return;
        }

        if(!event.getValue().equals(event.getOldValue())){
            cellItemAnswerMap.replace(getCellItem(), event.getValue());
        }
    });

    mainLayout = new VerticalLayout(stemHolder, hr, cioGroup);
    mainLayout.setWidth("600px");

    hr = new Hr();
    hr.setWidthFull();
    mainLayout.add(hr);

    binder = new Binder();
    binder.forField(cioGroup)
            .bind(CellItem::getCellItemOption, CellItem::setCellItemOption);
    changeCellItem();

    prev = new Button(VaadinIcon.BACKWARDS.create());
    prev.addClickListener(event -> {
        cellItemIndex--;
        if(cellItemIndex == 0){
            prev.setEnabled(false);
            next.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            prev.setEnabled(true);
            next.setEnabled(true);
        }

        changeCellItem();
    });
    prev.setEnabled(false);

    next = new Button(VaadinIcon.FORWARD.create());
    next.getStyle().set("margin-left", "490px");
    next.addClickListener(event -> {
        cellItemIndex++;
        if((cellItemIndex + 1) == cellItemIndexSize){
            next.setEnabled(false);
            prev.setEnabled(true);
        } else {            
            next.setEnabled(true);
            prev.setEnabled(true);
        }

        changeCellItem();
    });

    //this button is only to test if the current value for radiobuttongroup is removed/deselect when clicked!!
    mainLayout.add(new Button("TEST", event -> {
        changeCellItem();
    }));

    HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout(prev, next);
    buttons.setWidthFull();
    buttons.setJustifyContentMode(FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.START);
    mainLayout.add(buttons); 

    add(mainLayout);
    open();
}

//refresh components for new/previous set if item
private void changeCellItem(){
    stemHolder.removeAll();
    cellItem = ciList.get(getCellItemIndex());
    stem = cellItem.getItem().replace("{key}", cellItem.getItemKey().getItemKey());
    stemHolder.add(stem);

    cioGroup.clear();
    cioGroup.setItems(cellItem.getCellItemOptionList());
    cellItem.setCellItemOption(cellItemAnswerMap.get(cellItem));

    binder.readBean(cellItem);
    //binder.setBean(cellItem);
}

public TQCoverage getTQCoverage() {
    return tqCoverage;
}

public CellItem getCellItem() {
    return cellItem;
}

public int getCellItemIndex() {
    return cellItemIndex;
}

public int getCellItemIndexSize() {
    return cellItemIndexSize;
}

}
```

Comment: I see that you are having call both readBean(..) and setBean(..). You should use only one.

Comment: I have removed them already.. thank you for pointing that out.